# typescript template literal type with union all method

Tags: typescript

i need to union of all my key and method from object to a an enum

// i want that result
[ 'aStore.aMethod1','aStore.aMethod2', 'bStore.bMethod1', 'bStore.bMethod2' ,''bStore.bMethod3']
sample

```js
const objA = {
  aMethod1: function (_params: string) {
    console.log("obj A a method1")
    return 'A1'
  },
  aMethod2: function (_params: string, _param2: string) {
    console.log("obj A a method2")
    return 'A2'
  }
}
const objB = {
  bMethod1: function (_params: string) {
    console.log("obj b  bmethod1")
    return 'B1'
  },
  bMethod2: function (_params: string, _param2: string) {
    console.log("obj B bmethod2")
    return 'B2'
  },
  bMethod3: function (_params: string, _param2: string) {
    console.log("obj B bmethod3")
    return 'B3';
  }
}

const rootStore = {
  aStore: objA,
  bStore: objB,
}

// https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html
type actionName<T> = `${string & keyof T}.${'HELP'}`; 
///  how do i make typesafe here
// i want an action a list of [ 'aStore.aMethod1','aStore.aMethod2', 'bStore.bMethod1', 'bStore.bMethod2' ,''bStore.bMethod3']

// is there any way to make args type safe too.
function dynamicCall<T> (action: actionName<T>,...args:any) {
  // it will call objA
  const [storeName, method] = action.split('.');
  const store= (rootStore as any)[storeName];
  if(store&&store[method]){
     (store as any)[method].apply(undefined,args)
  }
}
dynamicCall<typeof rootStore>('aStore.aMethod1')
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArAgjAvDA3gWAFAxgEMBZAUygAsQATARgC4YAzAVzGCgEtwYAKAfQAOhAE6EAthEbQRnMAHMAlFjwECoSCAA2pAHRaQ83gCIEiGKkIxx5KnWOLVakeRYiwMAOTJanpwF8AGicSWxoAJkZWdi4eAWExSWkoWQVAmCFRCUiYGTklFXw1DQhtPQMjUyQLImsw6nCHJwIXKDcPb3C-Iv88XtwS2DMAIXRCgngyShoGZjYObg94rKTclPzlHCL1cFKdfUMTMxh4CZtp%200dtmFb2r2HfAOCiyfqc6IW4zMSpNdT5dLfbLJf6bZowEplA6VY6jeDnOyNK5qG6udz3LpPJyvC4AZii81iSyBqzyaQyCWBfw242KuyhFSO1ThCJouKa11u6M8w1xngA3AE%20ng8IMbiAQFAAMpQEAuMZbAiEGVy0iMMzIZ4TFUudVIYbPfp4AD0xpgFCgUEEUlNAHd7booABPQSkCDAWSCKBaQgKXRy%20TG6ggYAQY0UX3UeASgDWxvCxqgpHEgh9SYAtFpOEmxFp087XRBdBbxFo8AXSERPmAAHISUgAHgAKgA%20MYAAwAJJgyfIYAAyGAx0hOkBMGBN-y6bueAASAFEADIABU8-nb-JgJtNBCotpgwZgnGshGHMArEEITErFFILm3R5gtt9sF9VaJtSz0Dg44A2l5lVlFxdFCC5fECTxANVECpkRTx0k8eAdT0HE7HArwkKAlDYIiTwYAgxDkN0VC2U8ABdEVcB3TgIHPW95V9J0n0IJjZRPM9RHkWiK1yK9K1lEBdDwD4P2oJ0wAkThgAAYUILQtGbNteEIatGBUok6xsRTAl0XTOKkRiwSKajYFtTh5IhOStDgJBkCcMVf2gVVNNIdJWWoMixnUxZdAgVNs14TxdE8RRBSKMUnJcDBeBECVpSwohaMMxysJcsiwoITgmF4SLSH7ftct-dyyMURUURyhLCCSsAnUUIr6jIkDBFTJ1eDYahSCYORSGoQJ9ORGB%20n6MSJPEKTZPkhsKzHcVJWQltAqg4DQLQkKgA)

it will perfect if you can help to make an args typesafe too.
Thank you

Comment: Please let me know if [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3391m) works for you

Comment: You can also find more information in my [article](https://catchts.com/deep-pick)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mapped type to go through all the properties on the root type and build the paths:

```
type actionName<T> = {
  [K in keyof T & string]: `${K}.${keyof T[K] & string}`; 
}[keyof T & string]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArAgjAvDA3gWAFAxgEMBZAUygAsQATARgC4YAzAVzGCgEtwYAKAfQAOhAE6EAthEbQRnMAHMAlFjwECoSCAA2pAHRaQ83gCIEiGKkIxx5KnWOLVakeRYiwMAOTJanpwF8AGicSWxoAJkZWdi4eAWExSWkoWQVAmCFRCUiYGTklFXw1DQhtPQMjUyQLImsw6nCHJwIXKDcPb3C-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-AhOCYXh-1IcNw3Q91r2jRRFRRNC4KISD50XHD6mjXRCEEZ8TV4NhqFIJg5FIahAhnCBkRgfp+mbVtxHbLse3tU1zQrYDJR1UhnXfZU4OoqY7F8RQgA)

You can also get the parameters and the return type to type check:

```
type ActionName<T> = {
  [K in keyof T & string]: `${K}.${keyof T[K] & string}`; 
}[keyof T & string]

type GetMethod<T, M> = M extends `${infer K}.${infer SubKey}` ? 
  T extends Record<K, Record<SubKey, infer Method extends (...a: any) => any>> ? Method: never: never;

function dynamicCall<T>(store: T) {
  return <M extends ActionName<T>>(action: ActionName<T>,...args: Parameters<GetMethod<T, M>>): ReturnType<GetMethod<T, M>> => {
    const [storeName, method] = action.split('.');
    const store= (rootStore as any)[storeName];
    if(store&&store[method]){
      return (store as any)[method].apply(undefined,args)
    }
    throw new Error("Method not found")
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArAgjAvDA3gWAFAxgEMBZAUygAsQATARgC4YAzAVzGCgEtwYAKAfQAOhAE6EAthEbQRnMAHMAlFjwECoSCAA2pAHRaQ83gCIEiGKkIxx5KnWOLVakeRYiwMAOTJanpwF8AGicSWxoAJkZWdi4eAWExSWkoWQVAmCFRCUiYGTklFXw1DQhtPQMjUyQLImsw6nCHJwIXKDcPb3C-Iv88XtwS2DMAIXRCgngyShoGZjYObg94rKTclPzlHCL1cFKdfUMTMxh4CZtp+0dtmFb2r2HfAOCiyfqc6IW4zMSpNdT5dLfbLJf6bZowEplA6VY6jeDnOyNK5qG6udz3LpPJyvC4AZii81iSyBqzyaQyCWBfw242KuyhFSO1ThCJouKa11u6M8w1xngA3AE+ng8IMbiAQFAAMpQEAuMZbAiEGVy0iMMzIZ4TFUudVIYbPfp4KAAT0EpAsnzAADkJKQADwAFQAfAqnABtADSMDkMAA1qQTSAmDBHTAAGTUhQAXUYAAMACSYT3+XRJgNBkOOr3RiNR+T+OP8mB9d0Z4OhvNk+TRkW4U3mmAAcXIUzsTvSxFdGGIMFIAA8oKQwNQIDBE5g5ExSCIYCm05OwNPZ1KWPBPYHCzAAPwlophgdDkdjgBKpFAImo9s96TPF6vq-XgfSU5nMDbND7g+Ho74un-hCMIQYAmsoaCusBJrOq6u4ftQjBgKQABuM4IchM6CrgeAfESMDUCaYASJwwAAMKEFoWhOs6vAiBK0qyrqoZgkUXIePavaHj+Y7IFato2FR1GEFajA8USfEOi6gT-roojyL8AAKKzkDOED2i2UBwR277QYojBnm07iOmaDrqZpjqdtB6CuoqdKQLA7rQKq4npKy1C5hgQlEroECCFonBQLwni6J4iiYSiYqOS4GA0XROoWoQY6QYoDkMaQ4nRmFaicEwvCRaQ4bhnl7qudGig2SirF8HlRCJSByUlTJgi+SavBsNQpBMHIpDUIEskQMiaj9CilC0QA7jAiHjQAoiItEiCYcETZKzAgG1HIEP0-T4YR4jEWRFExZKcWKIFyqpTJcG+OkxgOEAA)

Comment: HI thank for your anwser. is there any way to make an args typesafe for mapping with the method too ? sample  dynamicCall('aStore.aMethod1', need  1 arguments is a string).  Thank you

Comment: @Mr.Trieu yes you can. Posted a version of that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Your assistance has saved me many many hours and I truly appreciate it.